# How does one run a C# web service from the command line?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, command-line

I assume I can just make an executable and then run that, but I can't figure out how to compile the whole service into a single executable. I've looked through the files in the solution and there isn't a single executable in there so i guess Visual Studio 2017 is doing some stuff to make it run. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I just need to know how to compile an entire C# web service into an executable that would run the same as running it from VS2017. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Into a single exe file? There's absolutely no official project type that gives you a single file as output. It also would help a lot what exact type of project you are working with, as there are many technologies for building web services in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

If you go with WCF, you can build a service running on NetTCP that is fully packaged into a single EXE file. It opens up the port(s) you specify for services to run on and will listen as long as the application is running.

See here for a demo: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dinlov/wcf-using-nettcpbinding/

I'm using this exact architecture (though far more files than a single EXE) as part of a Windows Service that is hosting NetTCP services, because at the time of development we were trying to avoid using IIS and this worked great. The demo above is configured via WinForms, but it should point you in the right direction!

Comment: any way to do this when the service i made is an ASP.net Web application?

Comment: If it's ASP.NET, then I'm pretty certain you're going to need IIS behind it. If you need to package the process up and let it be self-hosted, then WCF is going to be your best bet. It still operates like a web service (has a WSDL, can use XML and JSON, etc.), but it won't require IIS by going with it.